# Is there something like [Bind(Exclude="Property")] for asp.net web api?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, model-binding

I'm trying to exclude a property from my Post Action in a web api controller, is there something like `[Bind(Exclude="Property")]` for asp.net web api?

This is my model:

```
public class ItemModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I want to exclude the Id in the Post Action, because it is autogenerated, but I need to return it in my Get Action.

I Know I could have two models, one for my Post action and one for my Get action, but I'm trying to do this with just one model.

Comment: can set Id to a nullable int

Comment: It is really interesting what are you expecting when you ignore it (int). default? Some value will be there anyway. Please add more details about the generation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would favour mapping models but this could be achieved by checking if the request is a POST in a ShouldSerialize method:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string MyProperty1 { get; set; }
    public string MyProperty2 { get; set; }

    public bool ShouldSerializeMyProperty2()
    {
        var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;

        if (request.RequestType == "POST") return false;

        return true;
    }
}
```

Where your method name is the name of the property prefixed with ShouldSerialize.

Note this will work for JSON. For XML, you will need to add the following line to your config:

```
config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
```